# Преобразование const char [] в char * в Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, char

При компиляции моего кода в Visual Studio 2019 вылезает ошибка C2664: невозможно преобразовать аргумент из "const char [5]" в "char *". В то же время, у меня есть проект в Visual Studio 2017, где этот же код работает. Я не знаю, связано ли это с версией студии или с настройками проекта. Вопрос в том, можно ли как-то исправить эту ошибку настройками проекта, не меняя код? Про /permissive- читал, убрал его, не помогло.

Comment: Указатель на константный объект преобразовать в указатель на модифицируемый, это можно только с грубым преобразованием типа. Если вы будете модифицировать строку, программа упадёт. Если не будете, поменяйте тип аргумента на константный. Или чтобы всё скомпилировалось, сделайте **новую** строку (не константную).

Comment: Какой язык? C или C++?

Comment: @eanmos язык C++.

Comment: @ВладиславКрутенко, C++, начиная с C++11, запрещает приводить `const char *` к `char *`.

Answer (score 1):

Студия не была бы студией, если бы не разрешала делать страшное. Оказывается, большой кусок Windows SDK закладывается на то, что можно нарушить правило и скастить `const char*` в `char*`.

Вот сам ключ [/Zc:strictStrings-](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/build/reference/zc-strictstrings-disable-string-literal-type-conversion?view=vs-2019). Обратите внимание на минус в конце.

Почему оно раньше работало, а теперь нет? просто поменяли значение по умолчанию.

Но будьте осторожны. Используйте только в случае крайней необходимости.

Comment: интересно, кто же решил заминусить сегодня? грамманацци стандарта?

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне очень помогли.